# Discord Bot Python - Passing Unknown Amount of Arguments

Tags: python, object, parameter-passing, discord, discord.py

Currently messing about with the Discord.py Bot and I am struggling to pass multiple unknown values into this function. In this example I'm allowing the user to add multiple numbers but I don't know whether it will be 2 numbers of 200 numbers.

Using the code below I get an class object which I cannot seem to iterate through (discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x032AAB10).

My class inherits from the Music class from the following code, https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/playlist.py

```
class John_Bot(Music):

    @commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def add(self, *nums):
        result = 0
        for num in nums:
            try:
                result += num
            except:
                await self.bot.say("Numbers only please")
                break
        await self.bot.say("{} = {}".format((' + '.join(map(str, list(nums)))), result))
```

How do I get the variables out of this object? Most likely I've done something stupid or not fully understood what I am doing, so apologise in advance :D

Thanks,
John

Comment: Probably since `pass_context` is `True`, your first "number" is actually the discord context, not the number the person typed in. What happens if you set `pass_context` to `False`?

Comment: That has sorted out the issue! If you put it as a solution I will mark it as such :D

Comment: Well that was a random guess. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting that the context get passed to your function, which is becoming the first argument in `*nums`. Simply set `pass_context` to `False`, or change the function signature to `async def add(self, ctxt, *nums)`.